# Winecfg: error reading registry key for installroot

Tags: wine

I am new to Ubuntu.

I am trying to install `wine` so that I can install World of WarCraft on Ubuntu.  I installed  `wine` through the Ubuntu software center and saw that you had to type

```
winecfg
```

into the terminal in order for it to configure.

I get this response:

```
andrew@andrew-System-Product-Name:~$ winecfg
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/andrew/.wine'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x103e2b8, overlapped 0x103e2d0): stub
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10fe890, overlapped 0x10fe89c): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/andrew/.wine' has been updated.
^C
fixme:console:CONSOLE_DefaultHandler Terminating process 8 on event 0
fixme:console:CONSOLE_DefaultHandler Terminating process 43 on event 0
andrew@andrew-System-Product-Name:~$
```

I have no idea what any of this means...  Except err.  I'm assuming that means error.  No idea where to go from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

That's normal output the first time you run `winecfg`: see [this thread](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=14618).